# unpacking multiple arguments from a list in a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, arguments, argument-unpacking

I have two lists.

```
d1 = ["'02/01/2018'", "'01/01/2018'", "'12/01/2017'"]
d2 = ["'02/28/2018'", "'01/31/2018'", "'12/31/2017'"]
```

I am trying to get these values to be unpacked in a for loop.

```
for i,y in d1,d2:
    i,y = Startdate, Enddate
```

I realize this iteration will overwrite the values for **Startdate** and **Enddate** with each iteration but for now i'm just trying to successfully unpack the elements of each list.

I get the following error:

```
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I thought I was unpacking 2?  (d1 and d2)

Comment: `for i,y in zip(d1,d2):`?

Comment: `d1,d2` creates a tuple with two elements, your lists... each of your lists has three elements, which it tries to unpack into `i,y`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`zip`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/). Here is an experiment with `zip`:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> for i,y in zip(a,b):
    print(i,y)

1 4
2 5
3 6
>>>
```

You can say that your loop can be like:

```
for i,y in zip(d1,d2):
    i,y = Startdate, Enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop cannot "unpack" several list as you tried in you example, but you can 'zip' it as mentionner by @Nouman

> list(zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])) --> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]

You can now unpack the dates two per two...